# What will be the signature for this method in JNI?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

What will be the signature for this method in JNI?

```
public static <T> Field test(Class<T> test0, String test1)
```

Comment: Not sure, but probably same as for `public static Field test(Class test0, String test1)` because of type erasure.

Comment: The JNI signature for *any* method is provided for you via `javap -s`. Don't try to make them up yourself. Use the technology that is provided for the purpose. No need for asking questions on the Internet about this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

Just make a class and build it!

```
public class Test1  {
    public static <T> Field test(Class<T> test0, String test1) { return null; }
}
```

Then your JNI signature is obtained using the -s option of javap.  See "descriptor":

```
$ javap -s ./target/classes/net/redpoint/test/Test1.class
Compiled from "Test1.java"
public class net.redpoint.test.Test1 {
  public net.redpoint.test.Test1();
    descriptor: ()V

  public static <T> java.lang.reflect.Field test(java.lang.Class<T>, java.lang.String);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Field;
}
```

That being said, be *very* careful to match up the types of the generic when you make your JNI calls.  JNI is incredibly finicky and crashes in horrible ways.